# CSV file read result value set to entitiy object

Tags: c#, csv

I'm try to update OFAC Sanction list to my database by using following URL.

URL :

```
http://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.csv
```

This csv file has no any header and can download as a file. So I'm split all the record and get as a string Array. I have a problem with how can I assign those results to my entity object to save.

This is my Code :

```
List<SanctionOFACEntries> sanctionOFACList = new List<SanctionOFACEntries>();
List<string> splitted = new List<string>();
string fileList = GetCSVFileContent(url);
string[] tempStr;
tempStr = Regex.Matches(fileList, "(?:\"(?<m>[^\"]*)\")|(?<m>[^,]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray(); ;

int i = 0;

foreach (string item in tempStr)
{
    i += 1;

    SanctionOFACEntries sanctionOFAC = new SanctionOFACEntries();

    if (i != 1)
    {
        sanctionOFAC.Name = tempStr[i];
    }
}
```

This case that all the records are assign to array list correctly. If any one have this OFAC sample upload code send me .

Please help this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on your issue, but first of all, I'd recommend you use a csv library. I'm not clear on what your Regex is attempting to due, but I'm assuming it's trying to parse CSV. Using [`FileHelpers`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers) csv library, I've rewritten your code:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<SanctionOFACEntries>(); 
var sanctionOFACList = engine.ReadStringAsList(GetCSVFileContent(url));
```

Far more straight forward. Note your `SanctionOFACEntries` class should look something like this [Treasury Data Spec](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/SDN-List/Documents/dat_spec.txt):

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class SanctionOFACEntries
{
    public int ent_num
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string ent_num { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string SDN_Name { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string SDN_Type { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Program { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Call_Sign { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Vess_type { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Tonnage { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string GRT { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Vess_flag { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Vess_owner { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```